# I want to export candidate offer letter as pdf using taleo connect client

Tags: tcc, taleo

I want to export candidate offer letter as pdf using taleo connect client. How is it possible

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The tag for TCC is reserved for the compiler ([Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)).